# Standard command line syntax ambigiuty in interpretation rules?

Tags: command-line, standard

This question is somewhat similar to this: [Unix/Linux command syntax](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34297/unix-linux-command-syntax)

Suppose I have a program foo that takes arguments -a and -b. If both a and b take a string argument what is the meaning of this

```
foo -b -a bar
```

If multiple b:s are allowed

```
foo -b -a -b
```

??

Is there a true specification of the command line syntax somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you can find something that says option arguments can't start with a minus sign, then the only possible interpretation is

```
-b=-a
bar
```

See also: [POSIX Utility Conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02).

Comment: So I need to know if the option takes an argument or not, otherwise it will be impossible to know what it is.

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding.

Comment: @user877329 See also the [`getopt`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/getopt.html) function and the [`getopts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/getopts.html) utility. Most C programs use `getopt` (or a some extension of it that allows options to be more than one letter long, such as GNU `getopt_long`) and most shell scripts use `getopts`.